# phpmyadmin database upload breaking off

Tags: database, upload, phpmyadmin

I hope you can help pointing me in the right direction on this since I am a bit out of ideas.

I was running phpmyadmin to manage my wordpress databases sucessfully for over a year now. Some days ago I had to revert to a backup version of my database after the installation of a security plugin that did not work for my setup.

For some reason when uploading my .sql database file via phpmyadmin the upload seems to work fine for about 2 minutes and then suddenly breaks off displaying the error message "The localhost page isn’t working.localhost didn’t send any data."
About  3/4 of the tables are uploaded. (see screenshots)

I tried this with various database backups that did work in the past in combination with wordpress installations that did work until recent.

To my knowledge the parameters for post_max_size, upload_max_filesize, max_execution_time, max_input_time, memory_limit are sufficiently big to accomodate the upload file.

My Setup:
MAC BOOK, El Capitan
MAMP 3.5
WordPress 4.7.2
PHP 5.6.10

php.ini:
post_max_size = 800M
upload_max_filesize = 800M
max_execution_time = 6000
max_input_time = 6000
memory_limit = 1500M
Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)

Please let me know if you have an idea what might cause this issue and how I could fix it. If you need any specific additional information, please let me know.

Thank you for your support, have a good day,
Max

[Upload .sql.zip database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUwcM.png)

[import failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eQ7G.jpg)